# How to add hyperlinks in the help of a wxpython app?

Tags: python, hyperlink, wxpython, helper

I'm implementing the help menu of an App done in wxPython. By now, I'm using a txt file opened in a frame. I would like to have hyperlinks in the help text in order to open other txt files in the same frame. However, I don't know how to do this. I don't even know if this is the most elegant way to implement a help menu. Any suggestion will be very useful.

Below you can find part of the code I'm using (you will need a txt file called "Help_Main_App.txt"):

```
import wx

class Help_Frame(wx.Frame):
    title = "Help, I need somebody, help..."
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, wx.GetApp().TopWindow, title=self.title, size=(450,500)) 
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('#ededed')
        self.Centre()
        vBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.textbox = wx.TextCtrl(panel, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, size=(-1, 295))
        hBox.Add(self.textbox, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vBox.Add(hBox, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        panel.SetSizer(hBox)
        defaultdir, filename = './', 'Help_Main_App.txt'
        self.filePath = '/'.join((defaultdir, filename))
        self.textbox.LoadFile(self.filePath)
        self.textbox.Disable()


class Main_Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        #wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title = title, pos = (0, 0), size = wx.DisplaySize())
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(1000,780))
        self.Center()

        # Setting up the menu.
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        helpmenu = wx.Menu()
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"&Exit"," Close window and exit program")
        menuHelp = helpmenu.Append(wx.ID_HELP, "&Help"," Help of this program")

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"&File") # Adding the "filemenu" to the MenuBar
        menuBar.Append(helpmenu,"&Help") # Adding the "helpmenu" to the MenuBar
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)         # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.

        # Set event handlers
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnHelp, menuHelp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)


    def OnHelp(self,e):
        Help_Frame().Show()

    def OnExit(self,e):
        self.Close(True)  # Close the frame.                

def main():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Main_Window(None, "Main App")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using an HTMLWindow for something simple like that. It can handle only simple HTML, so don't try to make a website with it as HTMLWindow doesn't support CSS or javascript.

I wrote a simple About box using it. You can read about it here:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/06/11/wxpython-creating-an-about-box/

The basic idea is to subclass HTMLWindow and override its **OnLinkClicked** method. Then you can use Python's [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html) to open the user's default browser. Or you can try using subprocess, although that will be a lot less likely to work unless you always know what is installed on your target machines.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Mikes answer if you are able to use wxPython 2.9.4 or above you can consider using the more advanced html2 webview which does support CSS and javascript. Using this you could make the help as a simple website that can be viewed in program.

http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html

Its also worth mentioning that if (for some strange reason) you don't want to work with you could achieve a similar outcome with a StyledTxtCtrl.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but just for the sake of completeness (seeing that the OP's code was using **wx.TextCtrl** to show the help text), here is an example on how to add and launch hyperlinks using `wx.TextCtrl` (I have attached any explanations on the code comments):

```
class HelpDialog(wx.Dialog):
    """Help Dialog."""

    def __init__(self, parent, title, style):
        """Init."""
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent=parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, 
            title=title, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=wx.DefaultSize, style=style)
        # We need the 'wx.TE_AUTO_URL' style set.
        self.help = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, '', DPOS, DSIZE,
            wx.TE_AUTO_URL|wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RICH2|wx.TE_WORDWRAP)
        # Events - this is the interesting part, 
        # we catch the mouse on hovering the hyperlink:
        self.help.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_URL, self.openHlpUrl)
        # Show dialog
        self.ShowModal()
        
    def openHlpUrl(self, event):
        """Open help URL."""
        # We get the starting and ending points on 
        # the text stored in our ctrl from this event
        # and we slice it: 
        url = self.help.GetValue()[event.GetURLStart():event.GetURLEnd()]
        # We want to capture the left up mouse event 
        # when hovering on the hyperlink:
        if event.MouseEvent.LeftDown():
            # Let's be wxpythion native and launch the browser this way:
            wx.LaunchDefaultBrowser(url)
```